# External monitor stays on when MacBook Pro is in sleep mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I use an external screen with my Intel MacBook Pro for work, as well as the built-in display. I keep both screens on when I'm working, and I put the laptop into sleep mode when I'm not using it.

However, I've noticed that in sleep mode, the MacBook keeps the external display on (displaying black, but still on).

The display is an LG UltraGear 32GN63T, connected via DisplayPort through a USB-C dock. I have used this dock on a Windows laptop, and it turns off the display correctly when the Windows laptop goes to sleep. So, this isn't a dock problem, at least.

Is there a fix for this? (keep the external display off when the MacBook is sleeping)

Specs:

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019, Intel)
- MacOs Big Sur 11.7.1 (20G918)
- LG UltraGear 32GN63T

Comment: Are you sure it's the MacBook that is preventing the display from turning off? Does the display have a control panel menu where the delay is set?

Comment: @benwiggy it is not the MacBook, because I can shut down the MacBook and it lets the display turn off/go to sleep by itself like normal.

Comment: A dock is a very different animal.  Keep in mind the Mac will keep power to USB-C ports to facilitate power nap activities (like writing TM backups to an external drive) so, the dock stays awake. Windows does this differently and puts the ports to sleep

Comment: Does the USBC Dock have its own power supply you keep connected?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem with my LG 35wn75c. MacBook Pro connected via USB-C (DP alt mode), but no dock.

What fixed it for me was changing this setting **Battery > Options > Wake for network access** to Never (it was previously on "Only on power adapter").

Comment: Thanks for the answer and Welcome to Ask Different.  I am slightly confused by your use of DP Alt mode since my understanding is that Thunderbolt 3 encapsulates full DisplayPort and no USB-C alt mode is needed. Can you edit this if you know more or I’m incorrect?  https://www.anandtech.com/show/15752/displayport-alt-mode-20-spec-released (Perhaps you mean your display lacks thunderbolt so you know the Mac has to enable the less capable alt mode?)